# Removing the rows that contain the same value in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I want to combine the elements in list_a and list_b. Both list_a and list_b have the same elements.There are 5 elements in each list so the output should have 5x5=25. But I want my program not to print those 5 lines which have same elements.Please have a look at output.

`list_a=["apple","banana","melon","grape","orange"]
list_b=["apple","banana","melon","grape","orange"]

for x in list_a:
    for z in list_b:
        print(x,"-",z)`

apple-apple
banana-banana
melon-melon
grape-grape
orange-orange
Thank you

Comment: `[f'{x}-{y}' for x in list_a for y in list_b if x != y]`

Comment: To be clear, you _don't_ want the duplicate elements to appear in your list. Is that right?

Comment: just add `if x != z:` before condition before your print. That will exclude the same element products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you are looking for a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) with no duplicate rows.

If so:

```
>>> ['{} - {}'.format(a,b) for a in list_a for b in list_b if a!=b]
['apple - banana', 'apple - melon', 'apple - grape', 'apple - orange', 'banana - apple', 'banana - melon', 'banana - grape', 'banana - orange', 'melon - apple', 'melon - banana', 'melon - grape', 'melon - orange', 'grape - apple', 'grape - banana', 'grape - melon', 'grape - orange', 'orange - apple', 'orange - banana', 'orange - melon', 'orange - grape']
```

Or, on Python 3.7:

```
>>> [f'{a} - {b}' for a in list_a for b in list_b if a!=b]
```

To make your version work, just add a `continue` in your loop:

```
for x in list_a:
    for z in list_b:
        if x==z: continue
        print(x,"-",z)
```

Or,

```
for x in list_a:
    for z in list_b:
        if x!=z: print(x,"-",z)
```